# how to install unittyped and base-4.6.0.0?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform

I have the Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0 installed and I'd like to try out the unittyped package.

When I try to install it with `cabal-dev -s some-dir install unittyped` I'm getting the error:

```
$ cabal-dev -s some-dir install unittyped
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: unittyped-0.1 (user goal)
next goal: base (dependency of unittyped-0.1)
rejecting: base-3.0.3.2, 3.0.3.1 (global constraint requires installed
instance)
rejecting: base-4.5.1.0/installed-724... (conflict: unittyped => base>=4.6 && <4.7)
rejecting: base-4.6.0.0, 4.5.1.0, 4.5.0.0, 4.4.1.0, 4.4.0.0, 4.3.1.0, 4.3.0.0,
4.2.0.2, 4.2.0.1, 4.2.0.0, 4.1.0.0, 4.0.0.0 (global constraint requires installed instance)
```

and `cabal-dev -s some-dir install base-4.6.0.0` yields a similar message.

Is there a way to get past these errors?

Comment: **Never** even try to `cabal install base`. `base` is very tightly knit into your GHC, that cannot work. If you want `base-4.6.0.0`, install ghc-7.6.1.

Comment: And how one can know which ghc version is bound to which base version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`unittyped`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unittyped) package requires GHC >= 7.6, it uses `DataKinds` (well, `DataKinds` first appeared in 7.4, but the implementation was not yet complete; maybe `unittyped` would also work with 7.4) and explicitly depends on `base >= 4.6 && < 4.7`.

As noted parenthetically above, it *might* also work with ghc-7.4, to test that

```
$ cabal unpack unittyped
$ cd unittyped-0.1
-- edit the .cabal file to allow base-4.5.*
-- and bump the version, so that cabal doesn't think it cannot work with base-4.5.*
$ cabal install
```

That may or may not work.

The safe option is to install ghc-7.6.1, but that would mean dropping the Haskell Platform.

Comment: I got a `ghc: panic! (the impossible happened)` with 7.4.2, so I guess  I have to move to 7.6.

Comment: Looks like that. I hope dropping the platform won't be too bad for you.